# 大家免着惊 - how to pronounce?

Tags: songs, taiwanese

This song by 罗大佑 might be a little dated but it has an infectious rhythm and I would like to know more about it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vbIKFMn9mU

The lyrics are difficult to understand, very Taiwanese and full of references to temples and obscure events and places that outsiders would not necessarily know the significance of.

My understanding is that it's satirical and that it refers to social conflict and protests during Taiwan's transition to democracy. But maybe that's inaccurate. And the title is said to mean "Don't be afraid", not "Don't be startled" as I would have expected.

For starters, could someone please romanise the title so I have some idea of the correct pronunciation! The last character sounds like a very nasal "gyak".

For reference, the lyrics are below.

```
大家免着惊
---------

忠孝东路西对介寿大路遐　介寿大路公在中正大庙埕
介寿大路口号按作无开声　中正大庙埕内大家免着惊

有一个古早门城在铁枝路边企　当年隔壁阿本仔侵入著行在这
今仔交通闹热夹甲呒震动　恬恬不敢喘气孤单在眠梦

今仔这个古城亲像当在变　爱靠台湾同胞做主来表现
人人拢真认真打拼在赚钱　但是城市甘有机会出头天

忠孝东路西对介寿大路遐　介寿大路公在中正大庙埕
介寿大路口号按作无开声　中正大庙埕内大家免着惊

有一个现代庙埕在台北市镇路　和尚王爷甲阮惜甲花糊糊
朋友相招运动做伙来散步　烧香希望保庇万岁好前途

今仔这个灵堂亲像当在变　爱靠台湾同胞做主来表现
庙内庙外认真流汗沃土地　但是游街甘著拼来庙埕坐

免着惊　惊著免　免着惊来　惊著会变
免着惊　惊著免　免着惊来　惊著会变
免着惊　惊著免　免着惊来　惊著会变
免着惊　惊著免　免着惊来　惊著会变

忠孝东路西对介寿大路遐　介寿大路公在中正大庙埕
介寿大路口号按作无开声　中正大庙埕内大家免着惊

这个国家庙埕愈来愈赤恹　休闲抗议艺术相招来占领

黑轮醃肠豆花踏入大庙埕　亲像八仙过海来各展名声

今仔这个世界亲像当在变　爱靠台湾同胞做主来表现
信女善男认真生存喊救命　但是庙埕甘会替咱来收惊

忠孝东路西对介寿大路遐　介寿大路公在中正大庙埕
介寿大路口号按作无开声　大正大庙埕内大家免着惊
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ta-ke bián tio̍h-kiann It's the pronunciation of this title. Hope can help you.

Comment: Thanks @Josh! If you can offer any insight on how to understand the lyrics, that will also be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

He is right, but that's the Minnan pronunciation. In Mandarin, **dà jiā miǎn zháo jīng**.

此处的 "着" 同 "着急"中的着

Comment: It's a Minnan song, I want the Minnan pronunciation!

However I didn't realise that the 着 was a verb like 着急. I guessed (wrongly, it seems) that it went with 免. Thanks!

Comment: not went with 免. 

like `别过去`, 说`别过`是一个固定搭配一样....

免: 不要, 如: 免礼, 免费;;; 
着惊: 受惊;吃惊;;;; 

着, **zháo**, 多义词, 释义来自百度: 
[Snipaste_2024-02-01_09-07-52.jpg](https://s2.loli.net/2024/02/01/MJB4SD6uoGFZfUN.jpg)